# Multiple Jenkins jobs in parallel with Cucumber annotations

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, cucumber

I'm pretty new to Jenkins and trying to run or be able to run multiple jenkins jobs in parallel with different goals (inside my goals will have a mvn command, also cucumber @tags). Basically I want to run multiple cucumber tags on multiple jenkins jobs at the same time. From the research I've done so far looks like I have a few options - multijob or pipeline plugins..please advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't worry about any resource consumption, you can use separated jobs as below and also you can hook them each other or trigger them with one job via Jenkins features:

Example job configurations :

**1. job :**

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Smoke"
```

**2. job :**

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Regression"
```

Comment: The thing is that if I have them as separate jobs - they will run one after another. I need to be able to run them in parallel..after installing the multijob plugin I have difficulties in where to pass the goal for each job..

Comment: No, they can be run one after another or parallel. You can trigger job from another immedietly @geniu

Comment: yup..So I guess I just need more help setting this up..that's my main challenge

Comment: You can read documentation, here is your plugin to do that : https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=36602920#content/view/36602920 @geniu

Comment: Thanks for the info - let me give it a try.

Comment: Jenkins is really easy, you can do that while watching tutorials. Please accept my answer if it is ok for you..@geniu